# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "verdades del barquero"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

Leyendo [un artículo deportivo](http://www.marca.com/futbol/opinion/2017/03/09/58c1327622601d4e348b4643.html) hace un tiempo me encontré con la frase:

> Me parece mentira que tenga que venir yo aquí a cantar **las verdades del barquero** por omisión de la inmensa mayoría del periodismo deportivo español. No hubo remontada sino remolcada: el árbitro remolcó al Barça hasta los cuartos de final. Como dijo Mourinho en su día, a mí me daría vergüenza.

Traduciendo, con *las verdades del barquero* lo que el autor dice es que le toca a él ser la persona que diga las cosas como son, expresar claramente lo que otros no quieren decir o ver.

Me hizo gracia la expresión, que había oído otras veces, así que me puse a investigar su origen y di con no uno, sino dos en [este artículo de Fraseomanía](https://fraseomania.blogspot.com/2018/02/las-verdades-del-barquero.html):

> La más difundida se basa en la anécdota de un barquero, que algunos sitúan en el río Tajo a su paso por la Alta Extremadura. El individuo surcaba las aguas turbulentas del río en el paraje donde hoy se encuentra el pantano de Alcántara, llevando en su barca a los viandantes que querían atravesarlo para ir entre las localidades de Talaván y Casas de Millán. Cierto día un estudiante le pidió que le llevara en su barca gratis, pues andaba escaso de recursos, ante lo cual el barquero le respondió que lo haría de buen grado si conseguía impactarle con tres verdades irrefutables. Una vez habían alcanzado la otra orilla, el joven bachiller le dijo al barquero las dos primeras verdades: «*pan duro, mejor duro que ninguno*» y «*zapato malo, más vale en el pie que no en la mano*», en alusión a la antigua costumbre de quitarse los zapatos cuando el suelo estaba embarrado para no estropearlos. Cuando el barquero pensaba que ya no podría superarse, el joven le dejó impactado con una tercera verdad: «*si a todos pasas de balde como a mí, dime, barquero, ¿qué haces aquí?*».

Y luego:

> Hay una segunda posibilidad que relaciona este dicho con la mitología clásica. Según los antiguos griegos, las almas de los muertos eran conducidos por Caronte sobre una barca que cruzaba el río Aqueronte hacia el inframundo gobernado por Hades. Tras cobrarles una moneda por el viaje, el barquero advertía a los muertos de cuánto les aguardaba al otro lado del río, sin retorno posible al mundo de los vivos. Si éstos no tenían con qué pagarle o no habían sido enterrados debidamente, Caronte los  arrojaba de la barca sin dudarlo hacia las profundidades procelosas de aquel río.

La primera hipótesis tiene [otros defensores](https://www.libertaddigital.com/opinion/amando-de-miguel/el-origen-de-algunas-frases-hechas-28773/) con versiones parecidas (Salamanca en lugar de la Alta Extremadura). El hecho de que se localice en zonas de España me hace pensar que seguramente sea una expresión desconocida en Hispanoamérica: ¿es así? Si el origen fuera el de la segunda hipótesis entonces sí podría estar extendido a ese lado del español.

Así pues: ¿cuál es el origen? ¿Alguien tiene alguna fuente oficial donde nos explique de dónde viene esta expresión? ¿Se usa en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: En el CORDE aparecen casos de mediados del XIX: "Ahora le diré yo las verdades del barquero." (1841)

Comment: Primera entrada en el DLE en 1852: "Decir a uno las verdades del barquero" = "Decir dos verdades" = "La expresión clara, sin rebozo ni lisonja con que á alguno se le corrige ó reprende". En 1884 el DLE indica que la expresión puede ser "Decir a uno las cuatro verdades del barquero".

Comment: Más datos: en 1843 existió un folleto satírico de política llamado "Las verdades del barquero", y la expresión se encuentra en la hemeroteca de la BNE en un ejemplar del "Diario de Madrid" de 1797. Lo curioso es que algunos textos recojan "las tres verdades del barquero", como en el de 1797, y en otros sean cuatro, como acabó recogiendo el DLE.

Answer (score 1):

[Cecilia Böhl de Faber](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern%C3%A1n_Caballero) da esta explicación en *Un verano en Bornos*, pero ella insinúa que esta es una de múltiples:

> ... En cuanto á mí, que la tengo *meridional*, como dice Efi, y *efervescente*, como asegura D. Pío, no habría tomado la cosa tan flemáticamente, y ese amante fementido y desleal hubiese oído de mi boca **las tres famosas verdades del barquero.** ¿A que no sabes tú cuáles son esas tres verdades, de las que todos hablan y pocos averiguan? Pues yo te las diré, porque me las ha enseñado mi tío Miguel. Son:
>
> > **«peso y medida, cuenta y razón, y la verdad encima»;**
>
> **lo que significa: el peso, esto es, las piezas que lo componen, las taras; las pesas que marcan la cantidad, y la lengüeta que arriba marca la igualdad de las pesas y que se llama la verdad.**—Tía Belica explica estas tres verdades tan decantadas de otra manera; pero ahora no tengo tiempo de referírtelo, porque quiero proseguir mi relato, y contarte por sus pasos contados los *memorables eventos* que suceden en este Bornos, tan hipócritamente tranquilo, monótono é inocentón.
>
> - *[Un verano en Bornos](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m-BcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA373&dq="tres+verdades"+"del+barquero") (Carta XXI - Primativa á Teresa)*, Fernán Caballero (1864)

Ella empieza contar la otra origen de la tía en una obra anterior:

> - ¿No sabe usted que una de las tres verdades del barquero es, el pan duro... duro, más vale duro que ninguno?
>
> - [*Clemencia*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=010818%5C015%5CC003O01082018155153850.1020.1016&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+verdades+del+barquero%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), Fernán Caballero (Cecilia Böhl de Faber) (1852)

---

Manuel José Martín, casi 100 años antes, cuenta este chiste en su *Tertulia de la aldea* *(Pasatiempo III)* que parece ser la origen que has visto en el artículo:

> Caminaba un tunante Gallego con su mochila acuestas, y llegando á un rio sin puente, que solo tenía barca, se halló sin dineros para que el barquero le pasase. Suplicóle, no obstante, que le hiciese la caridad de pasarle ; pero el barquero le dixo, que diese quatro quartos. El tuno le respondió, como no los tenía, y que le pasase por el amor de Dios ; pero el barquero le respondió :
>
> > Señor Licenciado, déxese de plegarias, que aquí no estoy yo para trabajar de valde : en verdad, que con sus ruegos y caridad pagaré yo bien la renta, y llegaré á comer cascotes. Dé usted tres quartos, y al punto le pasaré.
>
> El pobre tunante le dixo:
>
> > Confiésole, buen hombre, que no me asiste una blanca ; pero le daré un equivalente si me hace esta gracia: **le diré las tres verdades del mundo**, que le pueden servir de mucho en adelante.
>
> Cuajáronle al barquero las tres verdades del mundo, y luego le mandó al Gallego tuno entrar en la barca. Díxole, que eran tres, y que se las diría una al comenzar á pasar del rio, otra al medio del rio, y otra al saltar de la barca á tierra. Quedaron concertados en esto, y al empezar á remar le dixo una, que fué:
>
> > “Pan mao é dur, mas vale, algun que ninguna”
>
> **Pan malo y duro, mas vale alguno que ninguno.** El barquero que oyó esta verdad, le dixo:
>
> > ¿ Qué verdad del mundo es esta? brava friolera.
>
> A que replicó el tuno:
>
> > “Mas, meu señore, non he verdade ó que digo?”
>
> > Si es verdad, hombre, retornó el barquero; pero es verdad de Pedro Grullo.
>
> > Perdone sua mercede, respondió el Gallego, que eu non sei outras.
>
> > Vamos con la segunda, dixo el barquero, que ya estamos en la mitad del rio :
>
> > "Ten vosa merced razon, oigame: Zapato boo ó mao, mellor está en ó pee, que non en á mao."
>
> **Zapato bueno ó malo, mejor está en el pie, que no en la mano.**
>
> > Otra friolera como la pasada, tornó á decir el barquero. Voto á las calzas de mi abuelo, que á saber eran de este jaéz sus verdades, primero le echara por el rio abaxo que pasarle.
>
> Respondió el Gallego :
>
> > "Perdone sua mercede, que eu non sei outras."
>
> Llegaron en fin á la otra orilla, y quando el barquero estaba ocupado en amarrar la barca, para que el rio no se la llevase, como tambien quando observó el Gallego que no tenía libertad para coger un remo, y molerle á palos, le dixo la otra verdad, que fué :
>
> "Si á toudos pasais como á min, masadero, ¿para qué traballais é istais aquin?"
>
> **Si á todos pasais como á mí, majadero, ¿ para qué trabajais y estais aquí?** Y al acabar de decir esto echó á correr, diciendo desde lejos:
>
> > "¿Hé verdade ista, meu amiguiño? ¿Hé verdade? Afei, que os fice mamola. Istas soin le as verdades da ó mundo, meu amigo. Perdone á sua mercede, que eu non sei outras.”
>
> El barquero como no podía soltar la barca, é ir tras el Gallego, se desatinaba y juraba, por no poder dar una tunda al tuno que tal burla había hecho de él.
>
> - [*Tertulia de la aldea*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-HvDA0mmedsC&pg=PA100&dq=verdades+del+barquero), Manuel José Martín (1782)

Comment: Mmmm de acuerdo, esto explicaría cuáles son las verdades del barquero. Sin embargo, ¿cuándo se "establecieron"?